# I can't 'HRESULT Authorize()' through 'interface IiTunes'

Tags: ios, iphone, com, itunes, ole

Good day, everybady,

I work on Windows7 (64 bits) and try use COM / OLE object "iTunesApp Class". This object has installed with iTunes application.
My code is following

```
  HRESULT hr;
  CLSID clsid;
  IiTunes *pIiTunes = nullptr;
  //Apple.iTunes
  CLSIDFromProgID(OLESTR("iTunes.Application.1"), &clsid);
  hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, nullptr, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, __uuidof(IiTunes), reinterpret_cast<LPVOID *>(&pIiTunes));
  if (pIiTunes != nullptr)
  {
      VARIANT data[16];
      OLECHAR ver[4096] = L"vaneustroev@gmail.com";
      pIiTunes->Authorize(1, data, (BSTR*)ver);
  }
```

Then (pIiTunes->Authorize(1, data, (BSTR*)ver);  )   I've got exception  '...exception from address 0x000007FEFF4E4FCA (oleaut32.dll) ...Violation of access rights at address 0x000007FEFF4E4FCA...'

I don't know which parameters for pIiTunes->Authorize() I must set

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the *value* of parameters that must be set, but I know the *types* of these parameters.

First one is a int32, second is a [VARIANT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373687.aspx) reference, third is a array of [BSTR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069.aspx). VARIANTs must be initialized and cleared after use, BSTRs must be allocated (a BSTR is *not* a OLECHAR *) and freed after use.

So, beyond the real semantics of the method, you can call it like this:

```
VARIANT data;
VariantInit(&data); // undercovers, this will just zero the whole 16-bytes structure

// ... do something with data here

BSTR ver = SysAllocString(L"vaneustroev@gmail.com"); // you should check for null -> out of memory
pIiTunes->Authorize(1, &data, &ver);

// always free BSTRs and clear VARIANTS
SysFreeString(ver);
VariantClear(&data);
```

If you use Visual Studio, there are cool [Compiler COM Support Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/compiler-com-support-classes) that ease VARIANT and BSTR programming considerably, as you could rewrite all this like this:

```
_variant_t data;
_bstr_t ver = L"vaneustroev@gmail.com";
BSTR b = ver;
pIiTunes->Authorize(1, &data, &b);
```

Visual Studio also provides a library called [ATL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/atl-classes) that has other [wrappers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288834/ccomvariant-vs-variant-t-ccombstr-vs-bstr-t). Using them is similar:

```
CComVariant data;
CComBSTR ver = L"vaneustroev@gmail.com";
BSTR b = ver;
pIiTunes->Authorize(1, &data, &b);
```